# Using "that...in" instead of "in which"

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to say the following?

> What we are doing is not being interpreted in the way **that it was meant in.**

Instead of...

> what we are doing is not being interpreted in the way **in which it was meant.**

I would appreciate it if you could specify the academic basis if possible.

Comment: @Robusto I think the issue here is a little deeper than ending a sentence with a preposition. The question appears to be dealing with prepositions in _that_ vs _wh_ relatives of a specific sort.

Comment: @DW256: I think the depth you see still leaves us in the same place.

Comment: @Robusto If the linked question's answers sufficed the _that_-relative example in this question would be perfectly acceptable, and instances of it would abound. Instead, it is vanishingly rare and, as Edwin Ashworth agrees in a comment above, is unacceptable. This is clearly a different issue than the one in the 'duplicate'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a *that* relative with the the head noun *way*, the preposition *in* is usually not included and the relativized element is an adjunct of means (how), not the object of a preposition.

> This process of learning is hardly an explicit one, it is the way
> **that** tacit knowledge is acquired -- learned.  (Studies in the Education of Adults; Learning expertise in practice: Implications for
> learning theory; JARVIS, PETER)

not

> ?This process of learning is hardly an explicit one, it is the way **that** tacit knowledge is acquired **in** -- learned **in**.

So the gap for the understood element is simply the whole adjunct.

> tacit knowledge is acquired (how?)

Further examples in academic literature:

> One of the most notable benefits of the digital revolution is the way
> **that** it facilitates collaboration. (Chronicle of Higher Education; The Job-Market Moment of Digital Humanities)
>
> The potential for such moderation to emerge is visible in the way
> **that** Sunni tribal leaders in Iraq have turned against al Qaeda to work with us; they could not stand the thought of living under such
> fundamentalism and brutality. (Foreign Affairs; America's Priorities
> in the War on Terror; Huckabee, Michael D.)
>
> It did not repeal the Militia Clauses in the way **that** the
> Twenty-First Amendment repealed the Eighteenth. (Michigan Law Review;
> THE SECOND AMENDMENT: STRUCTURE, HISTORY, AND CONSTITUTIONAL CHANGE;
> Yassky, David)

In fact, I've not come across an example with ***in***, and so suspect that it is excluded.

Examples on the Web:

> When 'gastronomy' was on the margins of attention it seemed big
> because it was an unexpected way to get at everything -- the nature of
> hunger; the meaning of appetite; the patterns and traces of desire;
> tradition, in the way **that** recipes are passed mother to son; and
> history, in the way **that** spices mix and, in mixing, mix peoples.
> ([The Atlantic](https://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2011/11/the-table-comes-first-adam-gopnik-on-the-meaning-of-food/247836/))
>
> The parallels lie thick on the ground here, though, as I noted
> earlier, not quite precisely in the way **that** Murray saw them.
> ([Marquette](https://www.marquette.edu/maqom/aimilianos.html))
>
> While the economic downturn must have some impact on legal immigrants,
> there is no indication that their numbers have fallen in the way
> **that** that those for illegal immigrants have declined. ([Center for Immigration Studies](https://cis.org/Shifting-Tide-Recent-Trends-Illegal-Immigrant-Population))
>
> Sceptics have sometimes questioned the effectiveness of international
> law, as it can not be enforced in the way **that** police forces
> preserve national laws. ([UN](https://www.un.org/WCAR/pressreleases/rd-d21.html))

Comment: @DW256 Thank you for your detailed answer. I am a high school student in South Korea, and the expression using "that ... in" above was presented as grammatically correct in my midterm test. It is very important for students in Korea to get a single question right or wrong, so could you add a comment or email me via hhy0303857@gmail.com citations of "When using a that relative with the the head noun way, ...", that are publicly verified or published? (It would be a great help for my objection.)

Comment: @hy857 I've added a few examples from reputable sources on the web. Hope this is what you were looking for. If you're looking for an authority that says something along the lines of 'You cannot use _in_ for this type of construction', I'm afraid I can't help. The sources I have do not list it as a possibility, but do not expressly proscribe it either.

Comment: @DW256 That's already a lot of help. Thank you very much!